# Polygonize specific raster values QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, vector, polygonize

I have a raster of 36 classes of the land cover in South Africa. However, I only need 4 of these classes and create a polygon out of these 4 classes combined.

I have now used the raster calculator to generate a raster where 0 = the values/classes I don't need and 1 = the 4 classes I need.

How can I polygonize just the value 1 from this raster? Or, how can I polygonize the 4 classes out of the land cover layer directly?

Answer (score 1):

Use the raster calculator to select the values you want e.g. `yourraster@1 = 4`, this will give you a binary output that you can vectorise i.e. cells with a value of 1 being the the cells in your original raster that had a value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can polygonize just the 1 values using SAGA's [Vectorising Grid Classes tool](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.0/shapes_grid_6.html). Just set Class Selection to One Single Class and set Class Identifier to 1.